# Web interface to view errors/exceptions in live system

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Errors/Exceptions in applications are currently logged to a log file. Unless someone examines these log files, we don't get visibility into number of errors happening. We are looking for a web application that can display different types of exceptions, their stats (graphs), etc. so that anyone can easily look at the interface or set up monitors to send an email when more than x errors happen in an application.

What are the best practices to monitor for exceptions and get notified?

Comment: Totally depends. You can create an email logger, obviously risky. You can use message-based logging and email/page aggregate counts. You can use a commercial tool like Nagios etc. You can have a task aggregate info from the log files. There are essentially unlimited options.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JSnapshot](http://jsnapshot.com/), it may be very useful for you.